# Same datatype, different data behavior

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a column in one of my tables with the datatype of `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE`. However, data in this column are being displayed differently such as:

some records display data like `02-NOV-17 02.26.22.000000000 PM -04:00`

and some other data display data like `19-APR-18 10.31.15.000000000 PM AMERICA/NEW_YORK`

Why is this happening? and is there a sql query that I can use to check where else in my tables this is happening (if it's happening somewhere else).

Comment: The formatting of the timestamp value is done by the SQL client displaying the data. Are you saying the same SQL client displays the same value differently? Or is this simply in two different SQL clients?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, same SQL client displaying the same value differently.

Comment: Looks like some values have been stored with region info and some with offsets, which is less helpful, and possibly not intentional? You can make it display as offsets consistently - but you can't infer a region from an offset (since they aren't unique, plus DST etc.)

Comment: @AlexPoole, hmm, this could be it. What if I use sysdate within my insert statement, how is it going to be inserted (with offset or not)? 

Also, is there a query that I can run to display all tables that include timestamp data with offset?

Comment: If you use `sysdate` it will be implicitly converted using your session time zone, which may be a region or an offset. If you use `systimestamp` it will keep the tiem zone info from that. I've included examples in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-5BC5D2C1-6506-49BE-8177-F743A46FDC09):

> `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is a variant of `TIMESTAMP` that includes a time zone region name or time zone offset in its value.

The values in your table have a mix of regions and offsets. Your client is displaying all values with their 'region', but it can only do that if it actually has one; if it has an offset then it shows that instead.

Demo with various values entered, including implicit conversion from session time zone:

```
alter session set time_zone = 'Europe/London';

create table t42 (test timestamp(6) with time zone);
insert into t42 (test) values (timestamp '2018-11-02 14:26:22.0 -04:00');
insert into t42 (test) values (timestamp '2018-04-19 22:31:15.0 America/New_York');
insert into t42 (test) values (systimestamp);
insert into t42 (test) values (sysdate);
insert into t42 (test) values (current_timestamp);
insert into t42 (test) values (current_date);

alter session set time_zone = 'America/New_York';

insert into t42 (test) values (systimestamp);
insert into t42 (test) values (sysdate);
insert into t42 (test) values (current_timestamp);
insert into t42 (test) values (current_date);
```

If you use `sysdate` it will be implicitly converted using your session time zone, which may be a region or an offset. If you use `systimestamp` it will keep the time zone info from that, which is usually (if not always) an offset rather than a region - it comes from the server operating system.

Then query with a format model using TZR for regions:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZR';

select * from t42;

TEST                                              
--------------------------------------------------
 2018-11-02 14:26:22.000 -04:00
 2018-04-19 22:31:15.000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
 2019-04-12 16:36:30.441 +01:00
 2019-04-12 16:36:30.000 EUROPE/LONDON
 2019-04-12 16:36:30.622 EUROPE/LONDON
 2019-04-12 16:36:30.000 EUROPE/LONDON
 2019-04-12 16:36:30.862 +01:00
 2019-04-12 16:36:30.000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
 2019-04-12 11:36:31.052 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
 2019-04-12 11:36:31.000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
```

You could display them all consistently with offsets instead, using TZD:TZH instead of TZR:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZH:TZM';

select * from t42;

TEST                                              
--------------------------------------------------
 2018-11-02 14:26:22.000 -04:00
 2018-04-19 22:31:15.000 -04:00
 2019-04-12 16:36:30.441 +01:00
 2019-04-12 16:36:30.000 +01:00
 2019-04-12 16:36:30.622 +01:00
 2019-04-12 16:36:30.000 +01:00
 2019-04-12 16:36:30.862 +01:00
 2019-04-12 16:36:30.000 -04:00
 2019-04-12 11:36:31.052 -04:00
 2019-04-12 11:36:31.000 -04:00
```

But you can't infer a region from just an offset, as those are not unique.

> I wonder if there's a query that I can run to get all tables that have a mix of regions and offsets?

Not a simple query; it should be possible with an XML trick but I seem to be hitting a bug, so until I figure that out, you can do it with an anonymous block that runs dynamic SQL:

```
set serveroutput on -- or equivalent for your client

declare
  l_table_name user_tab_columns.table_name%type;
  l_column_name user_tab_columns.column_name%type;
begin
  for r in (
      select 'select ''' || table_name || ''', ''' || column_name || ''''
          || ' from dual '
          || ' where exists (select * from "' || table_name || '" where extract(timezone_region from "' || column_name || '") = ''UNKNOWN'')'
          || ' and exists (select * from "' || table_name || '" where extract(timezone_region from "' || column_name || '") != ''UNKNOWN'')'
          as query
      from user_tab_columns
      where data_type like 'TIMESTAMP(_) WITH TIME ZONE'
  )
  loop
    begin
      execute immediate r.query into l_table_name, l_column_name;
      dbms_output.put_line('Both TZR and TZH:TZM in table ' || l_table_name || '.' || l_column_name);
    exception
      when no_data_found then
        null;
    end;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

The two `exists()` clauses look for any timestamp with time zone value which have an offset - reported by `extract()` as 'UNKNOWN' - and which have a region, and the dynamic query generated by the cursor only finds a dummy for a table/column if both conditions are met (i.e. it has both types). Hence the need for the exception handler inside the loop. If you actually want to find any stored with offsets then just omit the second `exists()` clause.

Comment: Ok, this is a good answer which clarified things and made more sense. I wonder if there's a query that I can run to get all tables that have a mix of regions and offsets?

Comment: @samg - added a dynamic SQL way to do that.